# How to initialize a data.table column with empty lists and loop over it?

Tags: r, list, data.table

I want to use a `data.table` to store several models in a column. I am currently creating the models one by one and want to store them by using a loop. Therefore, I will have to initialize a column of empty lists that can be used to store each model object encapsulated in a `list`. I have found a syntax that works for this purpose (see below), but I thought there might be a more elegant/concise version (or a totally different approach), maybe also using assignment by reference.

Side note: Since creating each individual model may use a lot of memory I cannot do this in a single call that would assign all models to the column by reference at once - therefore, a loop is required. At least, this is my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong.

```
ids = c(1,2)
DT = data.table(id = ids, x = rep(list(), length(ids)))
# assigning by reference returns an error (just for info)
DT[1, x:= list(c(2,3))]
# subsetting the list does what is desired
for (i in ids) {
  DT[i, "x"][[1]] = list(rep(i, 2)*3)  
}
DT
# id   x
# 1:  1 3,3
# 2:  2 6,6
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be missing a bunch of nested `list` calls :)

First and foremost, note that

```
> identical(rep(list(), 100), list())
[1] TRUE
```

You need to do

```
> rep(list(list()), length(ids))
[[1]]
list()

[[2]]
list()
```

instead.

Now, for the assignment:

```
> DT = data.table(id = ids, x = rep(list(list()), length(ids)))
> DT
   id      x
1:  1 <list>
2:  2 <list>
> DT[1, x:=list(list(c(2, 3)))]  # notice the additional `list()`
> DT
   id      x
1:  1    2,3
2:  2 <list>
```

Comment: You can also initialize like `DT = data.table(id = ids, x = vector(length(ids), mode="list"))` for almost the same result. There's also putting the rep inside `[]`, like `list()[rep(1L, length(ids))]`.

Comment: Nice, I knew I was missing some basic aspects. Thank you for the explanations and variants of solutions.